# Uncaught (in promise) Error: export not found at resolve (requireUniversalModule.js:90)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, redux, server-side-rendering

I am running my frontend code in react and doing server-side rendering using express.
Recently i did some changes and committed to my branch, mostly related to redux and updated my store.js file.

```
import universal from "react-universal-component";
import Loading from "./components/Loading";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";

// small function that allows page to be a string or a dynamic import function
// <UniversalComponent page={()=>{import('../../someFolder/Component.js')}}
// Its great for complex folder structures. You can leverage code completion
const determineHowToLoad = ({ page }) =>
  typeof page !== "string" ? () => page() : import(`./${page}`);

const UniversalComponent = universal(determineHowToLoad, {
  onError: error => {
    throw error;
  },
  minDelay: 700,
  loading: Loading,
  error: NotFound
});

const loadComponent = file => universal(determineHowToLoad({ page: file }));


export { loadComponent, universal };
export default UniversalComponent;
```

Whenever i am hitting my site, after fetching all static files it gives this error:

```
"Uncaught (in promise) Error: export not found
    at resolve (requireUniversalModule.js:90)"
```